# Django: how to handle added parameters?

Tags: django, django-views

The documentation is nice [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/).

They give us this example:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive, {'foo': 'bar'}),
]
```

But they dont precise how to get it in the views code!

In my index view here, where could read the parameter `foo` given above?

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'produits/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'liste_produits'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Produit.objects.order_by('-date_v_fin', '-date_v_debut')[:5]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        locale = translation.get_language()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.kwargs['year']` for the `year` variable in the URL itself will do the trick. `self.kwargs['foo']` will get the extra data passed in that dictionary at the end. In general, `self.kwargs['name']` will get the variable `name` passed into the URL. [Documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)